# AWS DyanmoDB Not Importing JSON File

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I'm trying to import a JSON file using the AWS CLI with the following command

`aws dynamodb batch-write-item --table-name Sensors --request-items file://sensors.json --returned-consumed-capacity TOTAL`

It continues to give me the following error message...

`Unknown options: --table-name, --returned-consumed-capacity, TOTAL, Sensors`

Why am I not able to import the JSON file? Am I entering the wrong command? Hoping someone can help me out a bit.

Comment: Valid parameters for batch-write-item here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/dynamodb/batch-write-item.html

Answer (score 0):

`batch-write-item` is a collection of separate `write-item`.  Meaning that each request is distinct and can be for one or more tables.

So `--table-name` is not valid at the batch level, it should be part of the requests in your `sensors.json` file.

`--return-consumed-capacity TOTAL` should be valid